# Google Analytics - Behaviour -> Events not showing events total

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, event-tracking

I have set up event tracking with Google Analytics.

I am using [analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/) implementation:

```
(function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
            i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
            i[r] = i[r] ||
            function() {
                (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
            }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
            a = s.createElement(o), m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
            a.async = 1;
            a.src = g;
            m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
        })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

        ga('create', 'GA-CODE', 'auto'); 
        ga('send', 'pageview');
```

and this is the code i use to track events using a label:

```
var title = 'default movie';

(... movie title changes on click ..)

ga('send', 'event', 'Movie', 'favorite', title);
```

This gives me the event category "Movie", with the event action "favorite" and event label "Title of the movie".

I can see the event tracking working correctly on my GA account. If I check **Real-Time -> Events** everything is working and I can see the events at the report on **Behavior -> Events**.

The problem starts when i want to do the report with all the events that have been tracked since the beginning of the campaign.

A couple of weeks ago, I checked **Behavior -> Events** and I could see there where **more than 200 events with Label A, but now i can only see 64**.

Why is it going down? Why is not counting all the events from the start of the campaign?

Please help, part of the campaign is to report which movie is picked as the "favorite" by the users.

Comment: How are you comparing them against the campaign? Are you adjusting your date ranges accordingly?

Comment: i just realized it was a problem with the date ranges Hahahhaa

Comment: than you for your help!

Answer (score 6):

This was just a problem with the date range. I didn't noticed the filter option on the upper right section of the interface. Almost had a heart-attack the first time I tried to made the report.

Comment: Had the same issue. Thanks for sharing